# No module named 'prettytable'

Tags: python, prettytable

I have an issue with importing prettytable in VS code, even though I installed prettytable using

```
pip install prettytable
```

I got the error

> No module named 'prettytable'

I tried `pip install prettytable -U` but no result.

Comment: Is your error when you try to install prettytable, or after you install it and when you try to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating and activating a virtual environment before `pip` or `pip3` installing prettytable? (Also try upgrading pip with the command: `pip install --upgrade pip`)

On Mac (create virtual environment) Command: `Python3 -m venv env` (activate virtual environment) Command: `source env/bin/activate`.

On Windows (create virtual environment) Command: `Python3 -m venv env` (activate virtual environment) Command: `env\Scripts\activate`.